# Pdf created from pdfsharp showing weird text in mobile

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I created PDFs using PdfSharp. Its working as expected when opened in PC/Laptop, but when I try to open it in Mobile it is showing weird text on all pages. 
I googled for the same but, had no luck.

[image: Please refer below screenshot]

I used Verdena font to write text .

```
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 7, XFontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: what pdf client are you using on mobile? can you try a different pdf reader? have you tried a different font?

Comment: I am using default drive pdf viewer that comes with mobile. It is rendering correctly in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: setting of pdf application preferences::`IIRC`, the setting is called `Use local fonts`. You can usually find it in the Page display section of the preferences settings, but over the different releases Adobe kept adding, removing or re-locating different settings
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502612/how-to-fix-square-boxes-in-pdf

Comment: what about acrobat on mobile?

Comment: and this will help you understand more about `pdf` fonts
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29

Comment: working fine in mobile acrobat

Comment: Thank you guys, there was problem with font. Now I'm using 'Courier' and its working as expected.

Comment: @kiran if my comments related to `font` helped you please mark my  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting of `pdf` application preferences::`IIRC`, the setting is called `Use local fonts`. You can usually find it in the Page display section of the preferences settings, but over the different releases Adobe kept adding, removing or re-locating different settings
Here are standard `pdf`fonts`
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29